# URL shortener with destination whitelist?

Tags: web-apps, web-services, url-shortening

We recently had our custom alias (set up to goo.gl) ripped out of Facebook because someone used it to create a bunch of spammy posts.

What shortening service and / or software is out there that would let us use a custom alias / DNS name and **whitelist specific destination domain names** are allowed to be used?

Ideally it'd have an open interface / API and just silently drop anything not on the whitelist.